# Show that $f(x)$ have even degree

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> $f(x)$, $g(x)$ are nonzero polynomials and $f(x^2+x+1)=f(x)g(x)$. Show that $f(x)$ has even degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show that $f$ cannot have any real roots and hence cannot be of odd degree (every odd degree polynomial has at least one real root). Hence it is of even degree.

Consider the roots of $x^2+x+1=x$. They are $\pm i$.

Now let $f$ have a real root, say $x_0$. Then $f(x_0) = 0$. Substituting this in the given relation, we get:
$$f(x_0^2+x_0+1) = f(x_0)g(x_0) = 0$$
Which tells us that if $x_0$ is a root of $f$, then so is $x_0^2+x_0+1$. Continuing in this way, if $x_0$ is a root, so is $x_0^2+x_0+1, [(x_0^2+x_0+1)^2+(x_0^2+x_0+1)+1],$ etc. (which are all distinct if $x_0 \neq \pm i$) leading to an infinite number of distinct roots. As $f$ is a polynomial, this is a contradiction.

Thus $f$ cannot have a real root. In fact, the only roots it can have are those that satisfy $x_0^2+x_0+1=x_0$, as then $x_0$ and $x_0^2+x_0+1$ will be the same, i.e. if $x_0 = \pm i$.

Notice that the argument does not depend on what $g$ is at all: $f$ can always be shown to have no real roots.